# Google Plus SDK delete account and revokeAccessAndDisconnect

Tags: android, google-plus

[Here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#revoking_access_tokens_and_disconnecting_the_app) it says:

> To comply with the terms of the Google+ developer policies, you must
>   offer users that signed in with Google the ability to disconnect from
>   your app. If the user deletes their account, you must delete the
>   information that your app obtained from the Google APIs.

Could that mean that I have also revoke access if user deleted the account from the android device itself?(if possible!) or it a delete button within my app? or both?

Cause the sentence is confusing! they used the word disconnect when they said I have to give them the ability to disconnect then after that they used word delete
when they say if user deletes their account!

Does they mean here I must provide disconnect button and delete button. or disconnect button also deletes the account?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the sentence (and almost whole SDK documentation for Google+ integration) is a little confusing. But I think it is supposed to mean that you have to provide a way to the user to disconnect their Google+ account from your app. As far as the "delete" part is concerned, you cannot keep the user data if the user deleted your app account or disconnected from Google+ within your app. 
And I don't think you can give them a "delete" button. Because AFAIK a user can't delete its Google+ account from your app. They might be talking about any account you created from the information provided by Google+ to your API, which can be deleted.